# NSURL returns file's id instead of file's path

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I make a Drag&Drop feature. And my NSURL returns file's id instead of file's path.

Code:

```
fileURL = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:[sender draggingPasteboard]];
```

What I receice:

> file:///.file/id=6571367.686377

What I want to receive:

> /Users/Desktop/someFile.png

How to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it's an NSURL object, so it's just

```
filePath = [fileURL path];
```

or more convenient

```
filePath = fileURL.path;
```

Comment: I little improvement: if a file URL is desired (for more convenient use for other APIs like AVFoundation, which seem to prefer URLs) in the "path variant" for any reason, you might get besser results using `-[NSURL filePathURL]`

Comment: @vadian i am having  trouble convert  `File reference URL to Path-based URL` my code is `let dropDataList = pasteboard?.propertyList(forType: NSPasteboardTypeFileURL) ` and i am getting output like this `file:///.file/id=6571367.68839675`...thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran into this problem today when updating an old Cocoa app.

To get the true path istead of a reference use .standardized on the URL.

`let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).standardized`